# Non-standard or Olympiad problems in probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to get a link or a book on non-standard or Olympiad problems in probability theory. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "40 puzzles and problems in probability and mathematical statistics" by Wolf Schwartz which I personally enjoyed solving very much. Another good book would be "Probability and Expectation"(Vol.14 from mathematical Olympiad series) by Zun Shan.